# Multiple subreports for each value in a field for a parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, subreport

I have a Report and a Subreport, with the Report having 30 instances of the Subreport organized to fit neatly on the page. The only parameter for the Subreport is Child and the only parameter for the Report is Parent (not the actual values but it might make it easier/more generalized for other people that see this). The data comes from a data source SQL_Source and stored proc dbo.StoredProc saved as Dataset1.

I need each subreport instance to use the next Child as its parameter from Parent. At the moment, each instance of the Subreport in Report takes in the parameter Child, but only the first value (with the name Child and value [Child]. If I set the value to Last(Fields!Child.Value, "Dataset1") then it will use the last value for the Parent as the parameter, so I know it can see them all. I'm simply trying to get it to retrieve all of them, which will be a variable amount depending on the Parent.

Sorry if it's a wall of text, anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can create a tablix of subreports, it will display the subreport for each Child as the tablix increments.

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, there's no function can work like an "opposite" Previous() function. For your requirement, I suggest a workaround is to join the parent and child table. Make each parent along with next child. Maybe you can submit a feature to MS and let them create a next() function or something like that.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit on what you mean by joining the tables? Also since the amount of values in Child will depend on the Parent, would I be able to have it print the 30 on the report page, and continue to print the 31 to 60 on the next, etc?

Comment: Actually I found a workaround - I learned that I can create a tablix of subreports, it will display the subreport for each Child as the tablix increments. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So, this _isn't_ actually the answer, and marking it as the answer is confusing.   You need to create an answer for your own question and then mark it as the answer  (if @Black_T helped you come to your solution, upvote his answer...)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote up, but I posted my answer.